# Error when trying to update a field in datagridview which is outer join

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, sql-update, outer-join

I have two tables called appointment and patient which have relationship with each other. I use outer join on appointment form to display the pFirstName field of patient table instead of the patientID. Now I want to try updating the pFirstName at appointment form, etc changing adam name to something else and clicking update button, but it gives me Invalid column name 'pFirstName'. Only this field cannot work since it is outer join. the other fields like aStatus, aDate works fine. Previously I was using commandbuilder to generate the update so cannot work for outer join for update, so I have to switch to this method which is manually typing the update query. Any help???

**APPOINTMENT FORM**
[image: APPOINTMENT FORM]

**APPOINTMENT AND PATIENT TABLE**
[image: APPOINTMENT AND PATIENT TABLE]

**Column 'patientid' does not belong to table** following @Ralf advice
[image: Column 'patientid' does not belong to table]

```
private void LoadAppointmentRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, pat.pFirstName, cen.mcCentre, nur.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT AS app";
            strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on app.patientid = pat.patientid";
            strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE as cen on app.mcid = cen.mcid";
            strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN NURSE as nur on app.nurseid = nur.nurseid";

            /*
            string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT";
            strCommandText += " AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID";
            strCommandText += " Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId";
            strCommandText += " left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
            */

            AppointmentAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter

            // Empty Employee Table first
            Appointment.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            AppointmentAdapter.Fill(Appointment);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Appointment.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdApp.DataSource = Appointment;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strQuery = string.Empty;
            string strQuery2 = string.Empty;
            DataTable dtChanges;
            //
            // Get the Updated DataTable back from the DataGridView
            DataTable dtAppointment = (DataTable)grdApp.DataSource;
            //
            // Get the Connection string from App.config.
            string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
            //
            // Get the Modified Rows by filtering on their RowState
            dtChanges = dtAppointment.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
            if (dtChanges != null)
            {
                //
                // Form the UPDATE Query to Update the Rows.
                objConn.Open();
                objCmd.Connection = objConn;
                for (int i = 0; i < dtChanges.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    strQuery = "UPDATE APPOINTMENT SET ";
                    strQuery += "aDate = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["aDate"].ToString() + "',";
                    strQuery += "pFirstName = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"].ToString() + "',";
                    strQuery += "aStatus = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["aStatus"].ToString() + "'";
                    strQuery += "WHERE appointmentID = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["appointmentID"].ToString() + "'";

                    //strQuery2 = "UPDATE APPOINTMENT SET ";
                    //strQuery2 += "pFirstName = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"].ToString() + "'";
                    //strQuery2 += "WHERE appointmentID = '" + dtChanges.Rows[i]["appointmentID"].ToString() + "'";

                    //
                    // Execute the Update Query.
                    objCmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                objConn.Close();
                dtChanges = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No update to change");
            }                   
        }
```

**Trying to follow @Ralf advice** I remove the var in each line of using (var objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand()) since it gives me A local variable named 'objCmd' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'objCmd', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else. But now i have this error, Column 'patientid' does not belong to table, whatever i try to update.

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strQuery = string.Empty;
    string strQuery2 = string.Empty;
    DataTable dtChanges;
    //
    // Get the Updated DataTable back from the DataGridView
    DataTable dtAppointment = (DataTable)grdApp.DataSource;
    //
    // Get the Connection string from App.config.
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
    //
    // Get the Modified Rows by filtering on their RowState
    dtChanges = dtAppointment.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
    if (dtChanges != null)
    {
        using (objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            objConn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtChanges.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                long? patientid = (long?)dtChanges.Rows[i]["patientid"]; // you must return the id in your sql to distinguish a needed INSERT from an UPDATE

                if (!patientid.HasValue)
                {
                    using (objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        objCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Patient(pFirstName) VALUES(@pFirstName); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
                        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", (string)dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"]);
                        patientid = (long)objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        objCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Patient SET pFirstName = @pFirstName WHERE patientid = @patientid";
                        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", (string)dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"]);
                        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid", patientid);
                        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                using (objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    objCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE APPOINTMENT SET aDate = @date, aStatus = @status, patientid = @patientid WHERE appointmentID = @appointmentID";
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", (DateTime)dtChanges.Rows[i]["aDate"]);
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", (string)dtChanges.Rows[i]["aStatus"]);
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid", patientid);
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointmentID", (long)dtChanges.Rows[i]["appointmentID"]);
                    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            objConn.Close();
            dtChanges = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No update to change");
    }            
}
```

Comment: You are updating APPOINTMENT but pFirstName is not part of APPOINTMENT. You need to UPDATE, INSERT OR maybe even DELETE on PATIENT if the pFirstName column has changed. First Insert or Update Patient retrieve the patientid and then update APPOINTMENT with the retrieved patientid.

Comment: Hmm, duno how to do it. Erm, now I have a strQuery at the update button there, I need to create another which is strQuery2 which is to update patient and retrieve patientid is it? @Ralf

Comment: Yes. Retrieving patientid is only needed when there was no Patient before and you need to execute an INSERT on the Patient Table. In the other case when an UPDATE is needed you should have it already. Just fetch patientid also with you initial select.

Comment: I updated my post. Is it like this? update patient table pFirstName too after appointment table pFirstName? But I duno about retrieveing the patientID.. @Ralf

Comment: No you still try to update pFirstName in Appointment Appointnment has no pFirstName it just has a patientid that might be updated if a new patient is created and attached top the appointment. And you should update patient before appointment since teh patient can be new. I tried a little guessing and put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guessed the datatypes in your DataTable and cleaned up the code (especially using Usings and Parameteres). You will need to return the patientid in you select Statement also to get it working this way.

```
if (dtChanges != null)
{
    using(var objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        objConn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < dtChanges.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            long? patientid = (long?)dtChanges.Rows[i]["patientid"]; // you must return the id in your sql to distinguish a needed INSERT from an UPDATE

            if (!patientid.HasValue) 
            {
                using (var objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    objCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Patient(pFirstName) VALUES(@pFirstName); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", (string)dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"]);
                    patientid = (long)objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }                            
            }
            else
            {
                using (var objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    objCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Patient SET pFirstName = @pFirstName WHERE patientid = @patientid";
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", (string)dtChanges.Rows[i]["pFirstName"]);
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid", patientid);
                    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            using (var objCmd = objConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                objCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE APPOINTMENT SET aDate = @date, aStatus = @status, patientid = @patientid WHERE appointmentID = @appointmentID";
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", (DateTime)dtChanges.Rows[i]["aDate"]);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", (string)dtChanges.Rows[i]["aStatus"]);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientid", patientid);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointmentID", (long)dtChanges.Rows[i]["appointmentID"]);
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
       }
  }
```

}

Comment: Omg can;t undestand, anyway I have updated my codes and added a image above, what;s wrong? I got error @Ralf

Comment: Don't remove the var. Remove your predefined objCmd Object in your code. Its not used. The commands get defined and initialized in the using block.

Comment: And to solve the problem shown in the screenshot you need to change the select statement in the LoadAppointmentRecords method. It must return patientid.